# Right click and Context menu event on ListViewItem

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my current implementation of `listview` with `gridlayout` in Javascript, if I right click on an item, a context menu which reads "Copy" shows up. I would like to overwrite this context menu event to select the element instead of showing "Copy".

So I would need to `addEventListener` on the `listViewItem` to listen to the context menu event. How will I be able to set the event listener on the listviewitems?

I tried to `addEventListener` on the `listview`, but I don't know how to check whether the 
`srcElement` is a item or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Right click to select ListView items are now a default behaviour in Consumer Preview. You can  also use Ctrl+Left Click to select items.